# Sorting arrays by highest to lowest then assigning a number from 1+ (as a rank) VB

Tags: sql, arrays, vba, ms-access

I am trying to sort an array based on highest to lowest and then assign a value to each item in the array. (I'm making a leader-board system with ranks)

For example:

```
Array(0) = 225558
Array(1) = 281158
Array(2) = 1131
Array(3) = 46212
Array(4) = 358119
```

sort it to

```
Array(0) = 358119
Array(1) = 281158
Array(2) = 225558
Array(3) = 46212
Array(4) = 1131
```

And then a value from 1+ to them, save it to the database.

I currently have:

```
 Dim lv, EXP, Floor, Logins As Integer
    Dim PKs, Mob, Deaths, Bounty As Integer
    Dim Total1, Total As Integer
    'Not yet used - Dim User As String'
    Dim inc As Integer

    con.Open()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "Count")
    Count = ds.Tables("Count").Rows.Count

    Dim Rank(Count) As Integer
    'Not yet used -' Dim Users(Count) As String

    For inc = 0 To Count - 1
        Users(inc) = ds.Tables("Count").Rows(inc).Item(0)
    Next

    For inc = 0 To Count - 1
        sql = "SELECT Lv FROM tblUsers"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "Lv")

        lv = ds.Tables("Lv").Rows(inc).Item(0)


        sql = "SELECT EXP FROM tblUsers"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "EXP")

        EXP = ds.Tables("EXP").Rows(inc).Item(0)


        sql = "SELECT Floor FROM tblUsers"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "Floor")

        Floor = ds.Tables("Floor").Rows(inc).Item(0)


        sql = "SELECT Logins FROM tblUsers"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "Logins")

        Logins = ds.Tables("Logins").Rows(inc).Item(0)


        sql = "SELECT PKs FROM tblKills"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "PKs")

        PKs = ds.Tables("PKs").Rows(inc).Item(0)


        sql = "SELECT Mob FROM tblKills"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "Mob")

        Mob = ds.Tables("Mob").Rows(inc).Item(0)


        sql = "SELECT Deaths FROM tblKills"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "Deaths")

        Deaths = ds.Tables("Deaths").Rows(inc).Item(0)


        sql = "SELECT Bounty FROM tblKills"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "Bounty")

        Bounty = ds.Tables("Bounty").Rows(inc).Item(0)


        Total1 = lv + EXP + Floor + Logins
        Total = Total1 - (PKs * 2) + Mob - (Deaths * 2) - Bounty



        'sql = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers"'
        'da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)'
        'da.Fill(ds, "Users")'

        'User = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(1)'

        Rank(inc) = Total

        'Saves total for each user row'
    Next
    'Trying to sort with users so that i can save it under the right user'
    Array.Sort(Rank, Users)

    con.Close()
```

Here I am making the calculation from data from the database.
When it comes down to the sorting I want it to assign a rank to them then save it to the database under the corresponding username.

Link to my database: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8HDvQ3oZFi6fjlXUU1wRklybVB0YS02MzlxM3pXQUxpdHVXU3JVbWpuNWMteVlVOVNLYkE&usp=sharing

Could anyone help me, my deadline is in a months time and I have no idea how to do this.

Thanks, Andy

Comment: Can you not just ORDER BY when you pull the data from the DB? You would usually only save a rank for historical reasons as its something that can be worked out dynamically.

Comment: Is this VBA or VB.Net? They are not the same. Please revise the tags and use only the appropriate tag.

Comment: Sorry its VBA not VB.net had the tags wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how the database part is related, but to answer  your sorting question...

First you need to increment all values with 1 as desired:

```
For i As Int32 = 0 To Array.Length - 1
    Array(i) = Array(i) + 1
Next
```

Now you could use LINQ for sorting:

```
Dim orderedDesc = From i In Array Order By i Descending
Array = orderedDesc.ToArray()
```

Or without LINQ, does not need to create a new array but sorts the orginal array:

```
System.Array.Sort(Array, Function(i1, i2) i2.CompareTo(i1)) ' swapped for descending sort
```

The LINQ version is more readable especially when it comes to descending sort.

Comment: Thx a lot, do you know how to when it is sorted to assign a ranking for them?